# How are pages like this generated in wordpress - example.com/?ite/41749raibtidm_html?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

not using any specific custom code, but getting these urls created. What should i check?

did not find anything in htaccess.

Comment: And what in Wordpress should create such URLs? What did you do that resulted in such a URL? How did you realize a URL looks like that?

Comment: did nothing for it, detected them in google search console. this is what i am trying to figure out, how are theyțre getting created

Comment: OK, that is something different. Those URLs are nothing that got created by your site. It is simply arbitrary URLs someone else lists. Why ever. Made up URLs. If someone puts a link into his site then bots will find and index it. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: What happens when you go to that URL, does that return any actual content, or just a 404? It might be a case of a hacked system, and now your site is used to provide spam pages. Try it in a private tab as well (if I was trying to place such pages on other sites, the first thing I'd do to try and avoid detection, is make them respond with a 404 if any admin was logged in.)

Comment: it shows homepage content when i load such a page

Comment: Of course it does, because those query parameters are not processed by WordPress at all and it just displays the home page. This is normal.